# generate dynamic input textfield by entering a number

Tags: javascript

[**JsBin**](http://jsbin.com/voyulogi/1/)

I am trying to add a dynamic input textfield using button click. it works fine. But, I want to add a textfield by entering a number. For example, if user entered a number (7) in input textfield I need to generate 7 input textfields. How do I complete this code?

**Javascript**

```
function add_f()
{
    var valu = document.getElementById("values").value;
    alert(valu);
    /* var extra_fields = document.getElementById("add");
    extra_fields.innerHTML += "<br><input type='text' />" */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input  name="values" id="values" maxlength="2" type="text" /><br>
<input type="button" value="Add more fields" onclick="add_f();" />
<div id="add">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping your textbox creation code inside a loop.  Ideally you'd do some checking to make sure the input number is valid or something, but this should get you started.

```
function add_f()
{
    var valu = document.getElementById("values").value;
    var extra_fields = document.getElementById("add");

    extra_fields.innerHTML = ""; //clear any existing inputs
    for (var i = 0; i < valu; i++) { //add new inputs until you reach 'valu'
        extra_fields.innerHTML += "<br><input type='text' />";
    }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/voyulogi/2

Answer (score 1):

```
function add_f()
{
  var container =document.getElementById("add");
  var value = document.getElementById("values").value;
  for(var i=0;i<value;i++)
   {
     var input = document.createElement('input');
     input.type='text'
     container.appendChild(input)
   }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/LHzb4/)